# How I can remove some pixels from image?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have image in flutter. I want to remove some pixels from image .In python we use OpenCV matchtemplate to remove pixels.

Comment: matchTemplate does not remove pixels. It finds the location of the match between the template and image. I do not know what you mean by remove pixels!  Do you mean to crop. If so, use lumpy slicing.  `new_image = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]`. where x and y are the start coordinates and w and h are the amounts to keep. The rest will be removed.

Comment: I do not have coordinates. I need to know coordinates to change color of  pixels. There are no some methods in flutter like matchTemplate .

Comment: I do not see how matchTemplate removes pixels. It is a template matching process. Do you have a template? If the template matches, then you should use Numpy slicing to crop the image to the match region. If you do not have a template image, then matchTemplate is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

> In python we use OpenCV matchtemplate to remove pixels.

In Flutter you include the [opencv](https://pub.dev/packages/opencv) package and you use the liked matchtemplate.

Comment: The package is not support all methods like OpenCV in python and c++.